# Rails 3.2 + jQuery + render partial in js.erb = broken HTML elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, render

The task is pretty simple: render partial template with OnChange AJAX function. 
After js.erb with render is executed I get broken HTML tags on my page new all rendered elements.
In this example it adds **'a>'** to the link name, so DOM contains **'New branda>'**.

```
#partial
<%= link_to 'New Brand', new_brand_path %>

#controller-------------------------
...
format.js

#parent view------------------------
<div id="partial-id">
    <%= render 'partial' %>
</div>

#action_script.js.rjs---------------
$("#partial-id").html("<%= escape_javascript(render ('partial')).html_safe %>");
```

Suggestions will be highly appreciated, I've already spent several hours trying to find out solution.

Comment: Is your JS template an ERB or RJS one (you mentioned "After js.erb with render is executed..." but `action_script.js.rjs` in code chunk) ?

Answer (score 2):

The problem solved once I switched from *Prototype* to *jQuery*. So the *action_script.js.erb* works well and `.html_safe` is not required in this case.

Answer (score 0):

For us with WODstack we use this quite a lot but we never ever use .html_safe.

Just remove your html_safe and you should be fine.

Comment: Thank, but I tried it. If I remove the .html_safe then I see not only 'New branda>', but the source of whole tag as a text.

Comment: This is the whole content of my partial:
<%= link_to 'New Brand', new_brand_path %>